# Git merge not pushing all merged files?

Tags: git, svn

Maybe I am doing something wrong but I am using git svn, and I do the following commands

```
git checkout master
git merge clean
git svn dcommit
```

The merge goes fine, deleting tons of files, merging files, adding files, but the git svn dcommit doesn't push all the files. I then do a git svn rebase to make sure were all up to speed, find and fix some conflicts and then commit and push again and I only see the files that were changed in the conflict getting pushed.

ideas?

Comment: If you read the man-page of `git svn` you will see that it clearly explains it's not possible to transfer Git merges to a subversion repository. Subversion has a fundamentally different (inferior) concept of branches than Git.

Comment: so if I want to merge two branches I do it in svn? >.> if so whats the true purpose of git svn?

Comment: The purpose is to provide a two-way bridge between Git and SVN. If you don't need merges, you can rebase your branches (to keep your history linear)

Comment: well this sucks......I hate merging in svn >.> thanks peeps

Comment: Well, then why do you still use SVN? Fully migrate to Git and be happy. Git svn was not written to iron out the wrinkles of Subversion's merge feature – or lack thereof. (Yes, tell me it has gotten better ever since with the introduction of merge properties. But be honest, merging in SVN just cannot compete with the merging capabilities of Git or any other distributed VCS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In git you should do rebase instead of merge to have linear history, then you could dcommit it into svn.